# When i am trying to deploy my node app in gcloud connection refuse error is occurring how to resolve this

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

when i am trying to deploy my node.js application in google cloud app engine its getting some error as below how to resolve it?

Here i am connecting the the cloud sql by using proxy. with felexible environement

Here are my code in app.yaml

runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

env_variables:
    SQL_USER: root
    SQL_PASSWORD: ''
    SQL_DATABASE: login_credentials

```
INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: mtab-chatbot-252808:us-central1:root2
MYSQL_CONNECTION: user:password@unix(/cloudsql/mtab-chatbot-252808:us-central1:root2)/login_credentials
```

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: mtab-chatbot-252808:us-central1:root2

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Object. (/app/customerConnectionHandler.js:27:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object. (/app/messageRouter.js:20:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! agent-human-handoff-sample@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the agent-human-handoff-sample@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-09-28T07_28_49_823Z-debug.log

Comment: How and where are you running the Cloud SQL proxy?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Connecting from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) page, there are few things you can check:

- Make sure you have the Cloud SQL Admin API enabled.
- Make sure your service account (by default its `service-[YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER]@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) has the correct IAM role or permissions (`Cloud SQL Client` preferred).
- Make sure you enabled the instance in the `app.yaml`:

```
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
```